# How to automatically start Ruby Version Manager

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is there a way to automatically load rvm on start up?

Every time I open a new terminal window I need to type `rvm 1.9.2` to be able to use the gem set. Can I add 1.9.2 as a default?

Comment: -1 on that question, since this is actually explained in the "Basics" section of the RVM docs (https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/).

Comment: The link the above commenter posted does not refer to rvm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways

The normal one is

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

You could also create a file .rvmrc which can also load a specific gemset per folder. For example if you have an application that uses the gemset 1.9.2@myapp, your .rvmrc in myapp could be:

```
# myapp/.rvmrc
rvm use 1.9.2@myapp --create
```

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to simply do this;

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```